# Ember Simple Auth + Devise throws 405

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ember.js, devise, ember-simple-auth

I'm using a stack consisting of Rails with Grape (for API stuff) and Devise (for user stuff), and Ember with Ember CLI and Ember Simple Auth. I want to implement authorization using the DeviseAuthenticator exposed by Simple Auth. My login controller looks like this:

```
// app/controllers/login.js

import Ember from 'ember'

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

  actions: {
    authenticate () {
      let {identification, password} = this.getProperties('identification', 'password')
      this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:devise', identification, password).catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason.error || reason)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

and my Devise authenticator setup:

```
// app/authenticators/devise.js

import Devise from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/devise'

export default Devise.extend({
  serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost:4200/api/v1/users/sign_in',
  resourceName: 'user',
  crossOriginWhiteList: ['http://localhost:4200/']
})
```

For development purposes, I've commented out the `error! "401 Unauthorized", 401 unless authenticated` part in my Grape config (that's another problem though) just to see if it even works, but it throws this:

`POST http://localhost:4200/api/v1/users/sign_in 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

I have no idea what to do, and as such would appreciate some help. If I can post more code from other files, I'd be happy to, just tell me.

Comment: `crossOriginWhiteList` doesn't exist anymore as auto-authorization was removed - you can safely delete that.

Comment: The setting should probably be `serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/sign_in'` (port 3000 instead of 4200) or are you using Ember CLI proxy mode? If you are then your Rails server doesn't allow `POST` requests to `serverTokenEndpoint: '/api/v1/users/sign_in'` which would be strange as `POST`s should actually be the only kind of requests that are ever sent to that route.

Comment: @marcoow my rails server is at `localhost:4200`. both rails and ember are running in different processes. also, what's ember CLI proxy mode?

Comment: Ember CLI usually runs on port 4200 and you cannot have Rails running on that port as well. Rails usually runs on port 3000. See the docs for `ember serve` here for info on proxy mode: http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-ember-cli

Comment: in that case, yes, i am using the proxy mode to `localhost:3000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that my devise routes are at `/users/sign_in`, not at `/api/v1/users/sign_in`.